# Mocking python subprocess.call function and capture its system exit code

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, subprocess

Writing test cases to handle successful and failed python subprocess calls, I need to capture `subprocess.call` returning code.

Using python `unittest.mock module`, is it possible to patch the `subprocess.call` function and capture its real system exit code?

Consider an external library with the following code:

```
## <somemodule.py> file

import subprocess


def run_hook(cmd):
    # ...
    subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
    sum_one = 1+1
    return sum_one
```

I can't modify the function `run_hook`. It is not part of my code. But, the fact is that `subprocess.call` is being called among other statements.

Here we have a snippet of code returning a forced system exit error code 1:

```
## <somemodule.py> tests file

import subprocess
from somemodule import run_hook

try:
    from unittest.mock import patch
except ImportError:
    from mock import patch


@patch("subprocess.call", side_effect=subprocess.call)
def test_run_hook_systemexit_not_0(call_mock):
    python_exec = sys.executable
    cmd_parts = [python_exec, "-c", "'exit(1)'"] # Forced error code 1
    cmd = " ".join(cmd_parts)
    run_hook(cmd)
    call_mock.assert_called_once_with(cmd, shell=True)

    # I need to change the following assertion to
    # catch real return code "1"

    assert "1" == call_mock.return_value(), \
           "Forced system exit(1) should return 1. Just for example purpose"
```

How can I improve this test to capture the expected real value for any `subprocess.call` return code?

For compatibility purposes, new `subprocess.run` (3.5+) can't be used. This library is still broadly used by python 2.7+ environments.

Comment: Actually, what do you want to test? Do you want to test that `exit(1)` will return 1. It sounds weird.

Comment: You can use [sys.executable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable) to get the Python executable instead of searching it in the paths.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE, I use it just for demonstration purposes. The complete test should cover how program is proceeding when some error occurs. But, before, I need to understand how catch system exit code.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE Thanks! I will update this call for `sys.executable`

Answer (score 1):

About [subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call), the documentation says:

> Run the command described by *args*. Wait for command to complete, then return the *returncode* attribute.

All you need to do is to modify your `run_hook` function and return the exit code:

```
def run_hook(cmd):
    # ...
    return subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

This will simply your test code.

```
def test_run_hook_systemexit_not_0():
    python_exec = sys.executable
    args = [python_exec, "-c", "'exit(1)'"]
    assert run_hook(args) == 1
```

My advice: use `subprocess.run` instead

**Edit**

If you want to check the exit code of `subprocess.call` you need to patch it with your own version, like this:

```
import subprocess

_original_call = subprocess.call

def assert_call(*args, **kwargs):
    assert _original_call(*args, **kwargs) == 0
```

Then, you use `assert_call` as a side effect function for your patch:

```
from  unittest.mock import patch


@patch('subprocess.call', side_effect=assert_call)
def test(call):
    python_exec = sys.executable
    args = [python_exec, "-c", "'exit(1)'"]
    run_hook(args)
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about this solution. But, I am developing under an environment where it is not possible. The run_hook is an external function.

I am looking for an approach to capture and store the return_value into the mocked call, without modify the run_hook function.

Comment: I updated the question to separate run_hook from my test code

Comment: For compatibility purposes, I can't use subprocess.run. This library is still used by python 2.7+ environments. (I will add all questions you are bringing to light to my original question. I appreciate your helpful insights)

Answer (score 0):

A wrapper around `subprocess.call` can handle the assertion verification.

In this case, I declare this wrapper as the `side_effect` argument in `@patch` definition.

In this case, the following implementation worked well.

```
import sys
import unittest


try:
    from unittest.mock import patch
except ImportError:
    from mock import patch


def subprocess_call_assert_wrap(expected, message=None):
    from subprocess import call as _subcall
    def _wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        if message:
            assert expected == _subcall(*args, **kwargs), message
        else:
            assert expected == _subcall(*args, **kwargs)
    return _wrapped


class TestCallIsBeingCalled(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch("subprocess.call", side_effect=subprocess_call_assert_wrap(expected=0))
    def test_run_hook_systemexit_0(self, call_mock):
        python_exec = sys.executable
        cmd_parts = [python_exec, "-c", "'exit(0)'"]
        cmd = " ".join(cmd_parts)
        run_hook(cmd)
        call_mock.assert_called_once_with(cmd, shell=True)

    @patch("subprocess.call", side_effect=subprocess_call_assert_wrap(expected=1))
    def test_run_hook_systemexit_not_0(self, call_mock):
        python_exec = sys.executable
        cmd_parts = [python_exec, "-c", "'exit(1)'"]
        cmd = " ".join(cmd_parts)
        run_hook(cmd)
        call_mock.assert_called_once_with(cmd, shell=True)
```

After some tests with taking this approach, it seems possible to use for a more general purpose calls, like:

```
def assert_wrapper(expected, callable, message=None):
    def _wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        if message:
            assert expected == callable(*args, **kwargs), message
        else:
            assert expected == callable(*args, **kwargs)
    return _wrapped
```

This is not the best approach, but it seems reasonable.

There is some best known lib with similar behavior that I can use in this project?